# Why am I getting the Moderator Engagement survey?

Tags: support, moderators, email, survey

I'm not a moderator on Stack Overflow (at least not that I'm aware of), but I received an invite to participate a survey where the questions appear to be aimed at moderators specifically, and not the SO community at large.

Are others getting this email as well? Is this intentional or am I marked as a moderator somehow I'm not aware of?

Comment: I was just about to ask this, as I got one too.  "We’d like to take a moment to thank you again for all you’ve done on ."

Comment: I *didn't* get this invite ಠ_ಠ Someone messed up real good...

Comment: Same here. Not a moderator and received the email.

Comment: me too. yup, yup, yup.

Comment: Got it, and not even with an e-mail address that is linked to an account. I think it was the e-mail address I gave in this BeNice survey a while back.

Comment: I am also not a moderator, so this means I become one? I want to :(

Comment: Quick check: Who here received the e-mail with the subject “Updates on inclusivity + a feedback request”? @BoltClock in particular.

Comment: I also got the email, and I came here to ask the same question

Comment: Came to check if, all of a sudden, I got moderator tools. False alarm :(

Comment: Got it as well, and I came on meta specifically to figure out if I missed something, glad to see I'm not the only one.

Comment: @Hermann Döppes: Not me. I never took that survey. The plot thickens...

Comment: 8 minutes, 17 upvotes, two comments with 7 & 6 helpful flags. What does it take to make this a "hot" MSO post?

Comment: @dfd http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @dfd: 8 minutes is not very long.

Comment: ...so should I take the survey or not?

Comment: "Not moderator, I just like surveys"

Comment: I really want to post an analogue of this question on our Teams Q&A site now...

Comment: @HermannDöppes, I also opted-in and got the "Updates on inclusivity" email

Comment: And the "we goofed" has arrived.

Comment: What, you hadn't heard they are rotating the entire mod staff?

Comment: Upvoted for *"at least not that I'm aware of"*, which leaves open the possibility that the mail *might* be intended for you. :)

Comment: I was wondering if I was a moderator without knowing it.

Comment: You're doing it wrong, the survey explicitly says "If you have any questions or concerns, contact Tim Post directly at tpost@stackoverflow.com." It does not say if you have any questions or concerns to post on Meta. Let's flood Tim's email!

Comment: Let's all take the survey anyway! Just make stuff up.

Comment: Actually @DavyM it says tpost@stackoiverflow.com, notice the _i_, he knew we were going to flood him with emails

Comment: @DavyM [it does not](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371887/3956566) :)

Comment: @KacosPro I think that's only on the screen when you finish the survey as YvetteColomb posted, but on the initial screen at [the link from the email](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/ZWWXB5H), it is exactly as I quoted it, with tpost@stackoverflow.com.

Comment: Oh! You're right @DavyM! Sending my email just now :D

Comment: @DavyM ahhh I see, you can be forgiven.. does that mean the other person took the survey? :D

Comment: I did take the survey @YvetteColomb, I was excited with my new role as a moderator :D

Comment: @KacosPro “How long have you been a mod?” *Not at all, so “less than a year”?* “Moderator on how many sites?” *None, so the closest answer is “only one”, right?*

Comment: Now everyone can take the survey regardless of the fact that one is a mod or not.

Comment: Right @HermannDöppes, and since I'm not very active on [so] but [es.so] in "I'm a moderator on (select all that apply):" I chose "_A Stack Exchange Network Site_".

Comment: I may or may not have taken the survey (͡° ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: I just love this bit in the apology email: _"You're receiving this email because we weren't paying enough attention"_

Answer (score 70, accepted):

This was a mistake on our end. In order to consolidate the places where we have people's contact information, we've been moving everything into one system. This has been *great*, we don't have to worry about spreadsheets and CSV files gathering dust in storage, but getting used to new stuff can get a little hectic.

We accidentally assigned the email to the wrong group. Fortunately, we realized it pretty quickly and sent out a subsequent apology and explanation.

#### Are you worried that non-mods got a link to the survey?

Not *really*, it's an informal 'how are things going' survey that was accidentally sent to a list of people that indicated a desire to help us with initiatives surrounding exclusion research. *Quite a few* corrected the typo in my email ([I take full credit for that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371881/why-am-i-getting-the-moderator-engagement-survey#comment616312_371887)) to ask about it; please just archive it and forget about it with our apologies.

#### Anything else to worry about?

No. Well, not surrounding this anyway. But don't *fully* trust that dietary fat intake actually has little influence on bad LDL levels until more research comes back.

Sorry about that, but as we like to say it, if it's worth doing, it's worth creating a small spectacle in the process! Or something like that. Actually we don't really say that, but I felt like it would be appropriate here.

Comment: *But don't fully trust that dietary fat intake actually has little influence on bad LDL levels until more research comes back* you're hilarious!

Comment: But why did we get different “We just goofed” e-mails? How did that happen? Do I need to ask a separate question for that?

Comment: Honestly, Tim, the humour surrounding this mistake has made for a fantastic start to my day, so please thank whomever done goofed :)

Answer (score 37):

Worse still. I got the email telling me they'd goofed up.

Even worse, proof that they really don't want to know what we think!

[image]

Comment: p.s. no community managers were injured in the creation of this post. Mr Tim Post has been informed of the email error.

Comment: Well, I mean, is it bad to spell it like I pronounce it? I just like talking like Bugs Bunny, and I AM NOT AFRAID TO ADMIT IT.

Comment: omg that does sound like Bugs Bunny!

Comment: Eh, what's up doc?

Comment: Wow, that's really shoddy! Proof reading? Peer review? Even just a spell-check? Tsk...

Comment: Skinheads and grumpy Londoners were identified as a main source of rude comments on SO. They have their own home now on stackoiverflow.com. They hate visitors so the domain is not reachable for anyone than themselves

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'd hazard that in some situations, there is no time for those. You know, for all we say, SO's crew's not exactly the most comprehensive of bunches, so when one breaks something, the pressure must be.. somewhat high. High enough that meager things like ortograph really comes second. There are millions of people watching.

Comment: ... Which might very well be a reason *in favor* of those. I am still presuming the typo to be an honest mistake, and not an advanced form of humor ;)

Comment: Falling off my chair, laughing :) @Pekka웃

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier When millions of people are watching, you get someone to proof read your two-sentence email before sending it. Don't tell me there's "no time" for that as it takes literally all of 30 seconds.

Answer (score 35):

## Official Reaction

Just in now:

> ### Please forgive us, we just goofed
>
> Please ignore our earlier email  https://stackoverflow.com/ Hello ,
>
> I would like to sincerely apologize. I just mistakenly sent you an
>   email that  was meant for Stack Overflow moderators. Please ignore it.
>
> Thank you for your patience,
>
> Anita M. Taylor,
>   Email Marketing
>
> You're receiving this email because we weren't paying enough attention. 
>   […]

(Some boring footer stuff has been redacted, the jewel has been preserved.)

## Speculation

Given that my e-mail address I received this under is not associated with any Stack Exchange account and the one person who did not receive it did not receive the e-mail with subject “Updates on inclusivity + a feedback request” ([Source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371881/why-am-i-getting-the-moderator-engagement-survey?noredirect=1#comment616268_371881)), they most likely just mixed up the recipient lists for those.

## Goofier Things

Apparently, [some people](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371881/why-am-i-getting-the-moderator-engagement-survey?noredirect=1#comment616310_371883) received a slightly different e-mail, where the first line reads

> Hello [redacted],

instead, which looks nicer. It is, however, fascinating to me that they managed to send different e-mails.

Comment: Yep. I just got this email too.

Comment: "WE GOOFED" nice

Comment: Huh.  I expected that to take 6-8 weeks. ;)

Comment: I just got my invite and now I'm second-guessing...

Comment: @AlexisOlson I've edited it in "for posterity."

Comment: @BJMyers I'm fine with editing in the subject (even though I would have done it with different markup choices) but I strongly prefer leaving the actual text intact. This is exactly the e-mail I received (minus some footer).

Comment: @HermannDöppes Apparently my email was different than yours.  I copied the text verbatim from the email I received - I assumed the run-on "please ignore" sentence was a copy/paste error.  If you prefer different markup, please go ahead and change it.

Comment: @BJMyers Faszinating. I pondered this possibility but I thought it would just be to strange if in their goof up they even managed to send different mails. Live and learn, I guess.

Comment: @BJMyers Much more important: We forgot the only interesting line in the footer, but I fixed that, too.

Comment: I'm the person who hit the Send button...walk of shame. Thank you everyone for having a sense of humor about it. I mistakenly sent the email to 2K people who signed up for Diversity and Inclusion updates, when it should have gone to 600 mods.

If you are a mod on both lists, you received 3 emails - 2 invitation to survey emails and 1 "we goofed" email. Please do take the survey, we really do want your opinion.

P.S. This is a cautionary tale for all marketers about sending emails before you've had your morning coffee.

Comment: What's even weirder: I received this, but **not** the survey email.

Comment: @AnitaTaylor I still have the open question about the fact that BJ Myers and I got different second e-mails. How did this happen? Regarding the coffee: [Worse things could happen.](https://twitter.com/juokaz/status/931304593132224512)

Comment: @tripleee Spamfiltering?

Comment: @HermannDöppes Believe it or not, I checked. But just as I checked again just now, the original survey email finally arrived in my inbox, a bit less that an hour after the "we goofed" email.

Comment: @HermannDöppes If you are a mod AND you also signed up for Diversity and Inclusion updates, you would have gotten three emails: 1) The initial invite, which went to whatever email address you used to sign up for the D&I updates. 2) The "We Goofed" email, which was identical for all recipients except for Display Name. 3) A second survey invite, which was identical to #1 -- unless you used two different emails for D&I vs. your regular moderator email. In that case, the two emails would be identical, except the second would have gone to your mod email address and listed sites you moderate.

Comment: This apology email ended up in a different folder in my gmail.  This one was a "promotion" instead of "update" from SO.

Comment: Bonjour _null_.

Comment: @tripleee "Please forgive us, we will be goofing in an hour"

Comment: @AnitaTaylor As the person who sends out the emails for the our company, _"You're receiving this email because we weren't paying enough attention"_ is all too familiar. But you should know, I laughed out loud and it made a great start to my day while simultaneously making my coworkers annoyed at how happy I am :)